# Identifying modified image in python

Tags: python, photoshop

Is there any way to identify the modified image with PIL in python? My question is: How can I use PIL to  identify modified image. By modified image, I mean any image that is by some way, modified using photoshop, GIMP or similar kind of software.

Update: Let's ask this in this way also. Is there any way to identify photoshopped image? Any software, tools etc, etc.

Comment: Modification compared to what?  If an image author creates an image with Photoshop, has it been "modified" by Photoshop?  If the author first creates it, but than does a few further modifications, was it modified?  If someone else does the further modifications, was it modified then?

Comment: I am understanding the complexity of the problem. But let's say this, I want to know if image is touched by some way with image manipulation software. However, this is not including something like: if I have photoshop installed in my computer, all images might be linked as 'open with photoshop' which might automatically make image associated with photoshop, at least for once.

Comment: My questions weren't meant to demonstrate the complexity of the task.  I was asking for clarification what you actually want.  What are the original sources of an image?  If the image has been *created* by Photoshop, does it count as *modified*?

Comment: @ Marnach: If created by photoshop, No.

Comment: There is no difference between an image created by Photoshop and one created by Photoshop first and modified later.  You cannot tell them apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use all the tools in PIL to figure out if an image has been modified. The problem is that figuring out is a very complicated task, so there is no easy, already implemented, method that you call and it tells you if the image has been manipulated.

You should read some papers on this topic just to see how difficult that is. After that you may (or not) want to implement the ideas presented in those papers using PIL.

Here's a [link](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=identifying+image+manipulation&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=on) with a search for such papers.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how it was modified!
It could be as simple as looking for a "Created by photoshop" string in the header

Alternatively there are a range of increasingly complex algorithms looking for lighting changes, difference in edge textures etc

[opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is probably a good place to start in python

Comment: What do you mean by "created by photoshop"? I don't want to know the initial state of the image but just the degree of modification.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades - it it is supposed to be an original photo from an iPhone and the creator field in the jpeg header says "photoshop" you could be suspicous